# Let $m, n \in\mathbb{Z}$ be positive integers with $m\leq n$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $m, n \in\mathbb{Z}$ be positive integers with $m\leq n$. Prove that there is a degree $n$ polynomial $p( z)$ with complex coefficients such that $p( z)$ has exactly $m$ distinct roots.

I have just started a linear algebra class and my notes and the book aren't helping me right now. I have no idea how to start this problem. Any help is appreciated.

My initial thought is to make $p(z)=a_nz^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_1z+a_0=0$ but I'm not sure how having $a_n$ be a complex number affects this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: As an aside, I would have considered this question more to do with complex analysis or abstract algebra than to do with linear algebra.  [The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) (*commonly proven in the aforementioned courses via different methods*) essentially says that any degree $n$ polynomial over $\Bbb C$ can be written in the form $p(z)=\alpha (z-a_1)(z-a_2)\cdots (z-a_n)$ where $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ are possibly repeated roots.

Comment: Alternatively, it says if $p(z)$ is a degree $n$ polynomial and $k$ is a root of $p$, then there exists a polynomial $q(z)$ where $p(z)=(z-k)^rq(z)$ where $q(k)\neq 0$ and $r$ is the multiplicity of the root and $q(z)$  is of degree $n-r$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Consider a polynomial of following form and think about how you can alter the powers of the factors:

$$
p(z)=(z-1)(z-2)\cdots(z-m).
$$